# WinRT decimal to string formatting

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I have a decimal value I need to display in XAML.

The problem with Win RT is that it does not support `StringFormat` in XAML.

I am trying to use converter then:

```
public class DecimalToCurrencyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is decimal)
        {
            return value.ToString("C2", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

the problem is that above approach does not work.

What I need really is to convert numbers like:

`1234.78` to  `1.234,78` or  `1 234.78` or  `1 234,78`

depending on parameters

How can I do it in WinRT?

Thank you!

Comment: "does not work"- what is the output?

Comment: It does not compile.

Comment: are you receiving an error stating "not all code paths return a value"? you need to return null after the if statement, for the non decimal values.

Comment: No... the code I provided is not exact, it is just an example

Comment: I can't help you with the compile time error because I don't know what it is, could you fix the compile error and update your question and show: 1 your code, 2. the wrong output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to understand here. numberformatting supporting in WinRt/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.numberformatting.aspx